# Timer supply to CPU in QEMU

Tags: c, embedded-linux, stm32, qemu, cortex-m

I am trying to emulate the clock control for STM32 machine with CPU cortex m4. It is provided in the [STM32 reference manual](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/3d/6d/5a/66/b4/99/40/d4/DM00031020.pdf/files/DM00031020.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00031020.pdf) the clock supplied to the core is by the HCLK.

> The RCC feeds the external clock of the Cortex System Timer (SysTick) with the AHB clock (HCLK) divided by 8. The SysTick can work either with this clock or with the Cortex clock (HCLK), configurable in the SysTick control and status register.

Now Cortex m4 is already emulated by QEMU and I am using the same for STM32 emulation. My confusion is should i supply the clock frequency of "HCLK" I have developed for STM32 to send clock pulses to cortex m4 or cortex -m4 itself manages to have its own clock with HCLK clock frequency 168MHz? or the clock frequency is different ?

If I have to pass this frequency to cortex m4, how do i do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

QEMU's emulation does not generally try to emulate actual clock lines which send pulses at megahertz rates (this would be incredibly inefficient). Instead when the guest programs a timer device the model of the timer device sets up an internal QEMU timer to fire after the appropriate duration (and the handler for that then raises the interrupt line or does whatever is necessary for emulating the hardware behaviour). The duration is calculated from the values the guest has written to the device registers together with a value for what the clock frequency should be.

QEMU doesn't have any infrastructure for handling things like programmable clock dividers or a "clock tree" that routes clock signals around the SoC (one could be added, but nobody has got around to it yet). Instead timer devices are usually either written with a hard-coded frequency, or may be written to have a QOM property that allows the frequency to be set by the board or SoC model code that creates them.

In particular for the SysTick device in the Cortex-M models the current implementation will program the QEMU timer it uses with durations corresponding to a frequency of:

- 1MHz, if the guest has set the CLKSOURCE bit to 1 (processor clock)
- something which the board model has configured via the 'system_clock_scale' global variable (eg 25MHz for the mps2 boards), if the guest has set CLKSOURCE to 0 (external reference clock)

(The system_clock_scale global should be set to NANOSECONDS_PER_SECOND / clk_frq_in_hz.)

The 1MHz is just a silly hardcoded value that nobody has yet bothered to improve upon, because we haven't run into guest code that cares yet. The system_clock_scale global is clunky but works.

None of this affects the speed of the emulated QEMU CPU (ie how many instructions it executes in a given time period). By default QEMU CPUs will run "as fast as possible". You can use the -icount option to specify that you want the CPU to run at a particular rate relative to real time, which sort of implicitly sets the 'cpu frequency', but this will only sort of roughly set an average -- some instructions will run much faster than others, in a not very predictable way. In general QEMU's philosophy is "run guest code as fast as we can", and we don't make any attempt at anything approaching cycle-accurate or otherwise tightly timed emulation.

Update as of 2020: QEMU now has some API and infrastructure for modelling clock trees, which is documented in docs/devel/clocks.rst in the source tree. This is basically a formalized version of the concepts described above, to make it easier for one device to tell another "my clock rate is 20MHz now" without hacks like the "system_clock_scale" global variable or ad-hoc QOM properties.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to know. Thank you so much @Peter.  I wanted to know is there any documentation available where I can get such information about the emulated platforms?

Comment: Also if I want to compare the real time clock and cpu clock and host clock differences how can I do that? Is there any option in QEMU - monitor? or I will have to tap a variable and print it?

Answer (score 1):

Systick is supplied via multiplexer and you can choose the AHB bus clock or divided by 8  system timer clock

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think the reference manual you are referring to is some other STM32 variant because for STM32407 this register does not exist. And my question was more related to how to connect this implementation with qemu

Comment: @ChandrikaJoshi I think you quite novice ARM programmer. This register **exists in all** Cortex devices and it is the part of the *core*. But to read about it you need to read the Programming Manual, not the Reference Manual which describes the peripherals

Comment: Yes this is my first project on hardware emulation and dealing with ARM processor. Could you please direct me to programming manual? Thanks.

Comment: @ChandrikaJoshi it is in the same place as RM. Go to STH STM webpage, find your micro. In the "Resources"you will have all the documents. BTW using emulators for the uCs is only waste of time. Buj the Nucleo board and use the real hardware

Answer (score 0):

An old thread and an oft asked question so this should help some of you trying to emulate cortex systems.

If using a .dtb when booting then in your .dts one can add to the 'timers' block a line of `clock-frequency = <value>;` and recompile it.  This will indeed increase the speed of cortex processors.  Clearly, value is some large number.